# How can you display info screen on iPhone during call

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

How can you (using API) display on-call / during call information in iPhone?

I searched in their API but couldn't get s solution so far. The screenshot below shows an example with Relaso One Android app.

[image: On call information about caller in Relaso One]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. When the phone application is running it is in control of the screen and your application will be suspended.